# Laravel 5.3 custom model cast type

Tags: php, laravel, casting, laravel-5.3

I developing system where money is basic thing, for now to show any price i am using accessors in model:

```
public function getFormattedPriceAttribute()
{
    return '$' . number_format($this->attributes['price'], 2); // TODO: implement currencies
}
```

But soon I will start implementing multicurrency and i want to make price showing as easy as define:

```
protected $casts = [
'price' => 'currency',
];
```

And custom cast for currency will format it as set in configuration.

Is this possible withot dancing with a tambourine?

Comment: I think a bit of a dance with tambourine is going to make your life much easier in the long run. I would create a separate class for managing Currency (with methods like 'eur', 'dollar', 'formatted' ... whatever you need) and cast all `price` attributes to this class (which would take value as constructor). Then you could do things like `$model->price->eur` or `$model->price->formatted`.

Comment: just a tip: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

**Cool**

I would create a Currency class, something like this:

```
class Currency {
    $value;

    public function __construct($value) 
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function formatted()
    {
        return '$' . number_format($this->value, 2);
    }

    // more methods

}
```

Then override the `Model` `castAttribute` methods, to include the new castable class:

```
protected function castAttribute($key, $value)
{
    if (is_null($value)) {
        return $value;
    }

    switch ($this->getCastType($key)) {
        case 'int':
        case 'integer':
            return (int) $value;
        case 'real':
        case 'float':
        case 'double':
            return (float) $value;
        case 'string':
            return (string) $value;
        case 'bool':
        case 'boolean':
            return (bool) $value;
        case 'object':
            return $this->fromJson($value, true);
        case 'array':
        case 'json':
            return $this->fromJson($value);
        case 'collection':
            return new BaseCollection($this->fromJson($value));
        case 'date':
        case 'datetime':
            return $this->asDateTime($value);
        case 'timestamp':
            return $this->asTimeStamp($value);

        case 'currency': // Look here
            return Currency($value);
        default:
            return $value;
    }
}
```

**Simple**

Of course you could make things much simpler and just do this in the `castAttribute` method:

```
// ...
case 'dollar':
    return  '$' . number_format($value, 2);
// ...
```

Comment: So, for now no way to "Inject" custom cast type to casts list?

Comment: Yeah simple and easy. The only thing is that you'll have to have this bloated method in the model, which is not nice. You could make it into a trait maybe.

Comment: I think, I will try to fork and make casting capsulated, when wil have free time.